# How to select the right div by class with Xpath?

Tags: php, html, xpath, domxpath

```
$divs = $xpathsuj->query("//div[@class='txt-msg  text-enrichi-forum ']");
$div = $divs[$i];
```

With this XPath command I'm able to select the div with the class "txt-msg  text-enrichi-forum " :

```
<div class="bloc-contenu">
    <div class="txt-msg  text-enrichi-forum ">
        <p>Tu pourrais &eacute;crire en FRANCAIS si ce n'est pas trop demand&eacute;?  
            <img src="http://image.jeuxvideo.com/smileys_img/54.gif" alt=":coeur:" data-code=":coeur:" title=":coeur:" width="21" height="20" /> 
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

But not this one :

```
<div class="bloc-contenu">
    <div class="txt-msg  text-enrichi-forum ">
        <p> 
            <img src="http://image.jeuxvideo.com/smileys_img/42.gif" alt=":salut:" data-code=":salut:" title=":salut:" width="46" height="41" />
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="signature-msg  text-enrichi-forum ">
        <p>break;</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: $div->nodeValue returns the innerHTML of <div class="txt-msg  text-enrichi-forum "> in the first case, but it returns nothing in the second

Answer (score 0):

I've tried it with both segments of XML and it seems to work with both, but there is a possibility that there is some issue with spacing.

In your XPath query, your looking for an exact match of `'txt-msg  text-enrichi-forum '` which has two spaces after `txt-msg` and one after the last part.  If any spaces are missing, then this will not find the element.

If you change it to...

```
$divs = $xpathsuj->query("//div[contains(@class,'txt-msg') and contains(@class,'text-enrichi-forum')]");
foreach ( $divs as $div )   {
    echo $doc->saveXML($div).PHP_EOL;
}
```

It should be a bit more tolerant.